# How can I have users upload multiple pictures like facebook?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload

How can I allow users to upload many images (code wise). I'm looking for plugins with examples or code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thought I'd direct you to my personal favorite solution for this:

http://www.plupload.com/

And my second favorite:

http://www.uploadify.com/

Just follow the instructions and it should be a snap!

Comment: For plupload, which is pretty cool btw, how can I edit the UI uploader? I uploaded their examples and I'm trying to get ride of the file size. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

[SWFUpload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) is the most popular solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for [SWFUpload](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/multiinstancedemo/index.php).  I'm not exactly sure what the specific code on this program is but I have used it a few times and saved me some time.  I wish it was easier to do multiple file/pictures at once but from what I've seen it is some what problematic.

Hope SWF works for you.

Comment: You can get the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/).  Hit the downloads tab on the top.